# Create a map of a building with kinect only?

Tags: navigation, mapping, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to mount a Kinect on our Coppa Robot. I'm still new to ROS etc. so my question is: will it be "enough" to create a map of a building? If I understood it correctly, TurtleBot is doing that and a lot more using Kinect only? So I'd just have to use GMapping to create a map and later amcl to estimate the position? That's it? (sounds a bit too easy) ;)

Update: it is possible only if you have really good odometry. Without it you can forget it (amcl might still work but gmapping won't).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12612/create-a-map-of-a-building-with-kinect-only?/) by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 345 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need the `pointcloud_to_laserscan` and `slam_gmapping` packages to accomplish this. You should have a look at `turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch` as a good example of how to accomplish what you want. You can find additional help in a number of questions on this board, including [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/409/2d-slam-with-gmapping-and-openni_kinect).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-01-12**:
Great, now I just need to wait for the kinect to arrive :)

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-12**:
I do believe so. I've never done it myself, but there's a lot of support for it on this forum.

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-01-12**:
Ok, thanks. So Kinect is enough to accomplish all of that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me the most tricky part turned out to be the odometry information passing. I took the base of this tutorial : http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

Altered it a bit to fit my needs, but it mostly remained the same. If you need any more help, let me know ;)

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-01-24**:
Same here, odometry is a pain. My robot does not have a stepper motor and I don't know how to calculate the speed. In my case it's just a value between 0-100. The actual speed depends on many factors (battery state, ground, laptop weight, ...) so measuring it is pointless.Any Idea how to solve that?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-03-23**:
A good Inertial Measurement Unit might help.

**Comment by [Cav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1633/cav/) on 2012-04-17**:
A gyroscope and setting the speed to a fixed value helps a bit.